# Could my camera been damaged if it was shipped without packing materials?

Tags: equipment-damage, compact-cameras

Amazon shipped me a camera like this: just in the manufacture's box with no extra padding in the shipping box.

Should I be concerned that it may have been damaged in shipping? Cosmetically it looks fine, but I'm concerned the internal moving parts (lens motor, image stabilization, etc) could have been damaged.

[image]

Comment: That's why I don't order such equipments online. Even if it is not damaged, if you e.g. test the autofocus system there is no way to know if the performance (which is never 100% accurate) is less than what it would have been had you picked up your camera at the store yourself.

Comment: @CountIblis I think that's just fooling yourself... there's no way to know how many times that camera was dropped in the back room of the store, or on the way there.

Comment: @CountIblis Where do those stores get their cameras from? They're shipped to them too, right?

Answer (score 7):

Compact cameras like this are most vulnerable when the lens is extended. When off, it should be able to take a few knocks, and the manufacturer's own box should offer a little extra protection.

Anything is possible, but my inclination is to say that any knock or impact strong enough to cause any damage would also have damaged the box. Since the box looks fine, I personally wouldn't worry.

However, if you *are* worried, contact Amazon — I'd be shocked if they didn't exchange it with no hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it could have. It could also have been damaged if it was shipped with the expected packing materials between the inner and outer box. The same camera could also have been damaged when shipped to a brick and mortar store.

If the retail box the camera is in shows no signs of a hard impact then it is doubtful that the camera was damaged while shipped inside the larger box. If it had moved around much within the larger box and had a hard stop against the inside of the larger box then the corners of the inner box would be crumpled. On the other hand, if an entire carton of these were shipped to a store snugly packed in a box made to hold an exact number of them with no room for movement the entire carton could have been dropped and landed very hard with no evidence of the drop visible on the outside of the retail boxes.

You pay your money and you take your chance. You also trust but verify. Test and use all of the features of your new camera before the return period has passed. Or at the very least, do so before the product warranty expires.